# AutoMapper Static Class Is Not Mapping List and Nested Entity

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core, automapper

I am using static class for mapping my entities. But if I use the following code, it is not working for converting lists and nested entities;

```
public static class MapperUtil<TSource, TDestination>
{

    private static readonly Mapper _mapper = new Mapper(new MapperConfiguration(
        cfg =>
        {
            cfg.CreateMap<TDestination,TSource>().ReverseMap();
        }));

    public static TDestination Map(TSource source)
    {
        return _mapper.Map<TSource,TDestination>(source);
    }
}
```

But if I use the following code it works well.

```
 var mapper = new Mapper(new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
 {
   cfg.CreateMap<List<User>, List<UserDto>>().ReverseMap();
 }));

 List<UserDto> userDto = mapper.Map<List<User>,List<UserDto>> (users);
```

Can anyone help me? (I am newbie).
**And is it good idea using static class for mapping? What is your solution for mapping as static class?**

Comment: Two code blocks are slightly different. You can try changing `cfg.CreateMap<TDestination,TSource>().ReverseMap();` with `cfg.CreateMap<TSource,TDestination>().ReverseMap();`

Comment: @serdar I think .ReverseMap(); doing it. Not Working.

Answer (score 0):

You should remove `List` in `CreateMap` method and create map for your types:

```
 var mapper = new Mapper(new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
 {
   cfg.CreateMap<User, UserDto>().ReverseMap();
 }));
```

Finally:

```
List<UserDto> userDto = mapper.Map<List<UserDto>>(users);
```

Comment: When delete List, It throws an error "AutoMapperMappingException: Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping." By the way, my question is about first code block.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using generic type for mapping, try below code

```
public class Source<T> {
    public T Value { get; set; }
}

public class Destination<T> {
    public T Value { get; set; }
}

// Create the mapping
var configuration = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => cfg.CreateMap(typeof(Source<>), typeof(Destination<>)));
```

Comment: Not Working: ```AutoMapperMappingException: Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping.```